# Apply a “long touch” event handler on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, angular, ionic2

With my team we are developing an app using Ionic 2, to help the people to navigate the streets considering accessibility restrictions.

The idea is that the user can touch doing a long press (for example 1 second) in somewhere on the map, and open a modal in order to he can report an issue in that point (for that latitude and longitude).

How can I apply a "long touch" event handler, similar a "press" in Hammer.js, on Google Maps?

Is it possible to get the coordinate where the user touchs in the map?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

I dont know whether there is a "Long touch" but we can get the coordinates on the user touch.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    title: 'Point A',
    map: map,
    draggable: true
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(event){
  console.log('Current Lat: ' + event.latLng.lat() + ' Current Lng: ' + evt.latLng.lng());
});
```

Hope it helps :)

( Here is some docs for maps [Doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) which helps you )

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The idea is that the user can touch doing a long press (for example 1 second) in somewhere on the map, and open a modal in order to he can report an issue in that point (for that latitude and longitude). Is this clear?